# Wordpress "Read More" button

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am working on My Wordpress Blog.

```
    the_excerpt(); & 
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
```

If I give Wordpress standard can add excerpt post like "Read More".
My code looks like this:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>
   "rel="bookmark" title="Read more on 
   <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

My question is how can I add an icon to Read More? Is there is any plugin for that? Or can we manually add this? Please help me to find a solution for this.

Comment: you want to remove the title and add icon?

Comment: this is a better fit for the WordPress Stack Exchange http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yha i want to remove the title and add a icon...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would add a class to the link like so;

```
 <a class="readmore" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Read more on <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"></a>
```

And then you would use CSS to apply your icon to that class like so;

```
a.readmore {
width: 20px;
height: 20px
display: block;
background: url(../images/myicon.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

These are examples, you would change the url path to your images folder depending on where it was relative to your stylesheet and you would upload your icon.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your comment - the_title() is removed.